# Fastest way to construct the sequence `c(1:1, 1:2, ..., 1:n)`

Tags: r, performance

For a given positive integer `n`, I want to know the fastest base R (not `Rcpp`) algorithm for constructing the integer vector `c(1:1, 1:2, ..., 1:n)`, which has length `n*(n+1)/2`. There are bonus points for fast *and* memory-efficient algorithms, since I ultimately want to avoid allocating a vector of length `n*n`.

I'm aware of at least two approaches:

- `unlist(lapply(seq_len(n), seq_len), FALSE, FALSE)`
- `{J <- .row(c(n, n)); J[upper.tri(J, TRUE)]}`

the latter being particularly inefficient since it allocates *two* integer vectors of length `n*n`.

Note that if we assign the value `.col(c(n, n))` to `J` above, then we obtain the sequence `1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 ...`. *This* sequence can be constructed fast and efficiently with `{i <- seq_len(n); rep.int(i, i)}`.

I am wondering if a similarly fast (or faster) algorithm exists in the `.row(c(n, n))` case, or if `unlist`-`lapply` is optimal from a base R standpoint.

FWIW, here is a benchmark of the three procedures I've mentioned so far:

```r
## Seemingly optimal for 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 ...
f0 <- function(n) {i <- seq_len(n); rep.int(i, i)}
## Candidates for 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 ... (the sequence I actually want)
f1 <- function(n) unlist(lapply(seq_len(n), seq_len), FALSE, FALSE)
f2 <- function(n) {J <- .row(c(n, n)); J[upper.tri(J, TRUE)]}

n <- 1000L
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f0(n), f1(n), f2(n), times = 10000L)
```

```
Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 f0(n) 1.711873 1.797891 2.112043 1.810273 1.836636 14.96644 10000
 f1(n) 1.986737 2.108630 2.472612 2.148195 2.214369 15.16282 10000
 f2(n) 3.785981 4.624821 5.551115 5.051405 5.861954 17.28740 10000
```

(I'm aware that `f1` is pretty close to `f0` here, but is there something better than `f1`?)

Comment: `c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4)`

Comment: I've fixed the title...

Comment: I guess you could tried Rcpp if you want a fast and memory-efficient solution.

Comment: f0 is not identical to f1. f1 obtains the desired result but f0 goes `1 2 2 3 3 3 ...`.  That said I'd expect a solution similar to f0 to be the fastest obtainable in base R, if nothing else simply because it casts all the looping to C++. The "slowness" likely comes from the forced memory allocation when converting ALTREP sequences to in-memory sequences through concatenation basically one of the following being compact format while the other is not: `.Internal(inspect(1:10)); .Internal(inspect(f1(10)))`. The "Fastest" would be to create a new ALTREP class in C/C++ for this specific purpose.

Comment: Yes, only `f1` and `f2` do what I want. I only included `f0` in the benchmark to see how `f1` and `f2` compared to the "fast" way to do an analogous (but not identical) task. I'll edit and try to clarify...

Comment: I think `sequences` is the fatest R solution already if you don't want to use Rcpp

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I'm guessing you mean `sequence`? Wow, somehow this function has evaded my base R radar for the longer part of a decade. Hiding behind `seq`, I guess. I would accept that as an answer if you'd like to write one, ideally with a benchmark.

Comment: Yes, it is `sequence`, I mean. I see that you have one benchmark with it :)

Comment: @Oliver Your last point about this sequence being completely specified by `n` and thus amenable to `ALTREP` is well-taken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're aware of, but if function from `base` is okay, try `sequence`.

```
f3 <- function(n) {sequence(1:n)}
```

It seems it's almost 2~3 times faster than `f0`

Comment: Thanks - I _was_ unaware of this function. It does seem to be the correct base R way to get exactly the result I want.

Answer (score 2):

I think `sequence` is the one you are after (if you are not going to use `Rcpp` for a even faster version)

```
f1 <- function(n) unlist(lapply(seq_len(n), seq_len), FALSE, FALSE)
f2 <- function(n) {
  J <- .row(c(n, n))
  J[upper.tri(J, TRUE)]
}
f3 <- function(n) {
  v <- 1:n
  data.table::rowid(rep.int(v, v))
}
f4 <- function(n) sequence(1:n)

n <- 1000L
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1(n), f2(n), f3(n), f4(n), check = "identical")
```

---

**Benchmarking**

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1(n), f2(n), f3(n), f4(n), check = "identical")
Unit: microseconds
  expr    min       lq      mean  median       uq     max neval
 f1(n) 3928.8  4144.50  5185.839  4227.5  4289.15 67457.1   100
 f2(n) 9490.3 10083.90 14415.777 12951.0 15080.50 78014.2   100
 f3(n) 8083.5  8572.10 12154.922  9063.0  9534.45 75408.7   100
 f4(n)  213.9   425.05   787.637   442.6   494.00  7844.4   100
```

Comment: I don't think my session knows `rowid`.

Comment: @MikaelJagan Sorry that I forgot to mention it is from `data.table` package

Comment: It should be `sequence(1:n)`? microbenchmark has `check` option.

Comment: If that is the case Park's deleted answer was correct, let's vote to undelete.

Comment: @zx8754 yes, already done that

Comment: I've accepted the earlier answer, which I guess was invisible to me since I don't have a privilege. Thanks for your comments/corrections.

Answer (score 1):

These 2 may also be options-

```r
n <- 5

unlist(purrr::map(seq(5), ~seq(.x)))
#>  [1] 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5

unlist(mapply(FUN = function(.x) seq(.x), seq(n)))
#>  [1] 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>